# height:100% overfills the content

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a header (with dynamic height!) and a content. The content should fill out the rest of the page - even if it has not enough text in it.

So far it's a question which is asked many times and is always answerd with something like code I've tried:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ff0;
}
.content {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

my problem is that with this code the height of the `.content` does not just fill out the rest of the page but it has something like the screen size as height. However with this code I have to scroll to see the bottom of the .content.

the code: http://jsbin.com/bilux/1/edit

At the moment there appears a scroll bar when I set the .content height to 100%:

[image: image with the problem]

**edit:**

thanks for the ways to solve that for a static header height! But isn't there a way to do that without knowing the height of my header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `calc` function like this:

```
.content {
 min-height: calc(100% - 50px);
 background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Also note that the default margin of body may make unexpected result, you should also reset it to zero.

[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/6NDNB/2/)

**UPDATE**: If you want it more dynamic, I'm sure you can try using *flex-box* layout, but it's still not supported widely (just the latest versions of the most modern browsers. For older browsers you should add libraries like [prefixfree](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)). Another solution is you can try using *table-layout* for the header like in this [updated demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/6NDNB/4/)

Comment: but what if i dont know the height of my header?

Comment: You guess. Read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**You're using 100% of the page**, *while other elements* use up some of that space. Trim down your percentage based on the space used. For example, on my website it needs 92%

The **WIDTH** and **HEIGHT** element is based on the **BODY** of the page (which is based on the **HTML** of the page), and not the space it has available. So 100% is 100% of the on-screen space. While other elements on the page may use 10% of that space, and push the content to 110%.

It's the same concept when your page fills with content, and you get a scrollbar. The height of the body is growing based on the height of the content areas container holding the growing content.

Answer (score 0):

`absolute` positioning might be the answer. Depends on the structure of your entire page. Check it out http://jsbin.com/qeveroci/1/edit